# Is there any way to navigate to a specific photo album from UIImagePickerViewController?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I know it is possible to show ALL photo albums by setting the source of a `uiimagepickerviewcontroller` to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`. However, is it possible to then navigate to a specific album if it exists?

Comment: Not possible using the standard `UIImagePickerViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

No this cannot be.

Unfortunately,The `UIImagePickerController` is a private, system class, which doesn't really allow alteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this using `UIImagePickerController` but you can iterate through the gallery album.
Here is an example [CustomPhotoAlbumDemo](https://github.com/rahulmane91/CustomAlbumDemo).